# Titanium Android 7 bluetooth paused

Tags: javascript, android, bluetooth, titanium, beacon

Dears i have a problem of pause during the scanning of bluetooth RSSID.

**Only for the Android >= 7** every 20 seconds of scan will **be paused for about 12-15** sec (the some for different device).

I use the LogicalLbas Andoid Module 1.2.9 and i try the SDK Titanium 5.5.1 to 6.3.0.

From the other blog i understand i need from now to update the Mode of Usig the Bluetooth. But i haven't the metod. I try to add here but doesn't change the problem. AnyOne solve this Issues?

**1) SET**

```
foregroundScanPeriod: 600,         
foregroundBetweenScanPeriod: 200,   
backgroundScanPeriod: 5000,        
backgroundBetweenScanPeriod: 6000
```

i try to insert here->

```
BluetoothLE.setScanTimers({
            scanPeriod : 600,
            scanPausePeriod : 200
            //here
        });
```

**2) SET**

```
setting= {
                  "allowDuplicates": true,
                  "scanMode": 2, //SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY
                  "matchMode": 1, //MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE,
                  "matchNum": 3, // MATCH_NUM_MAX_ADVERTISEMENT
                  "callbackType": 1 //BluetoothLE.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES
                }
```

i try to pass here
BluetoothLE.startScan( null , null , setting);

**3) and i add to tiapp.xml**

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

......

```
   <service android:name="com.logicallabs.bluetoothle.ScanService">
                <meta-data android:name="longScanForcingEnabled" android:value="true"/>
            </service>
            <receiver
                android:name="com.logicallabs.bluetoothle.BootReceiver"
                android:label="BootReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

...

Comment: You do not see this problem on Android 5 or 6?

Comment: No problem for the older Android , works correctly without pause for Android <= 6